# How to change height of only one row in a Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm creating a Tkinter-based GUI in Python, and I can't find out how to change the height of **only one** row.
I've tried this code, but it changes height of **every** row.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


root = Tk()
Style(root).configure("Treeview", rowheight=40)
tree = Treeview(root, style="Treeview")
tree.pack()
for i in range(100):
    tree.insert("", END, i, text=str(i) * i)
root.mainloop()
```

I've also tried to use the style for certain tags, but it doesn't work.
How can I do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change height of only one row in a Treeview?

I don't think you can change the height of a single row. The treeview was designed to have uniform rows.