# Python tkinter: table with variable row height possible?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

For my sqlite-based search Python script (a kind of two-language translation dictionary, i.e. translation memory), I've decided to use tkinter and show results in a treeview.
Everything works OK, except for the fact that for longer strings, text gets truncated: table rows are always 1 line high. If I change row height, it then applies to the whole treeview, which is not what I want.
Judging from Brian Oakley's answer here:
[How to change height of only one row in a Treeview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107432/how-to-change-height-of-only-one-row-in-a-treeview)
it seems that having variable row heights in a treeview is not possible.

So, my question is whether it is possible (using tkinter) to have a table with e.g. 3-4 columns, in which I can vary row height, depending on number of lines of wrapped text?

Perhaps something using listboxes or labels?

This is what I have now with treeview:
[image: treeview with truncated text in rows]

And this is what I would like to have (note different row heights in the table - this was done in Perl/Tk):
[image: Table with variable row heights]

So, is there any way to have such table with variable row heights, using Python and tkinter?